# Laravel 5.1: Elastic Beanstalk worker tier setup queue

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I follow [this blog](http://www.lifeofguenter.de/2015/04/laravel-queues-with-supervisor-on.html) to setup sqs in worker tier. But I get the following error, it seems the daemon doesn't get the environment variable correctly.

[image: Error log]

What I want to achieve is the worker tier to process all background jobs including cronjob & queue job.

**P/S: The values in *.env* file I stored in elastic beanstalk configuration**

Answer (score 0):

I've update this part

```
[program:laravel_queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/app/current/artisan queue:work sqs --sleep=3 --tries=3
stdout_logfile=/var/app/support/logs/laravel-queue.log
logfile_maxbytes=0
logfile_backups=0
redirect_stderr=true
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startretries=86400
user=webapp
numprocs=1
redirect_stderr=true
```

I also [blog it down here](http://jslim.net/blog/2016/07/19/setup-cronjob-and-queue-in-elastic-beanstalk-with-laravel/)